# Regex find/replace multiple text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I’m struggling a bit with some regex find/replace..

I want to search for some terms and when it finds any of them, it removes the line they’re on and the next line.
Terms I want to search for will have quotation marks and commas in them.

These are typical search terms (inc. the quotation marks):

**"TEXT TWO",BB**

**"TEXT THREE",AA**

**"TEXT FOUR",AA**

Typical file (will be 1000’s of lines long) contents:

```
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT ONE",AA | more text
Line 1
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT TWO",BB | more text
Line 2
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT THREE",AA | more text
Line 3
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT FOUR",BB | more text
Line 4
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT THREE",AA | more text
Line 5
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT FOUR",AA | more text
Line 2
```

I’d like the result to be:

```
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT ONE",AA | more text
Line 1
#text:0 first="blah" second="TEXT FOUR",BB | more text
Line 4
```

i.e. any line containing any of the above 3 terms would be completely deleted - along with its following line.

I tried a regex search/replace of:

Find what:-

```
.*"TEXT TWO",BB.*\R.*(?:\R|$)|.*"TEXT THREE",AA.*\R.*(?:\R|$)|.*"TEXT FOUR",AA.*\R.*(?:\R|$)
```

Replace with:- (left blank)

When I do the ‘find’ and ‘count’ , it correctly says 86 matches.  If I do the ‘Replace’, it says it has replaced 86 matches – BUT it has actually removed thousands of lines.
Confused…
Can you help please?  Do I need some extra quotations or escape characters?

Comment: I think this may be related to the greediness. Did you experiment with the ". matches newline" option? Does this affect the result?

Comment: it is working perfectly for me with inputs you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, don't check `. matches newline`.

You could also simplify a bit:

```
^.*(?:”TEXT TWO”,BB|”TEXT THREE”,AA|”TEXT FOUR”,AA).*\R.*(?:\R|$)
```

Comment: I’m not using .matches newline.
When it makes the change, it tells me it’s made 86 (correct amount) – but thousands of lines have actually disappeared.
When you say it worked perfectly, did you have other lines in the text?

Comment: @sjw: Strange, I just tested it and works fine. Wich version of Npp (here I have 7.5.8)

Comment: I'm using 6.9.1 (latest I'm allowed on this PC) - but had same results on your version which is why I thought it may be good to try on a different version anyway.  (also, same results with the simplified suggestion.)

Comment: Then you have some other characters somewhere. Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52184192/edit) and add real test cases. Are the quotes you're using really `”` and not`"`

Comment: I’ve done a find for any “ or ” – there are none.
Is there a limit of 'or's in a find/replace?
The file has over 45k lines too.
If I select the query and do a ‘find next’, and step through it only finds valid solutions.  When I do the ‘replace all’, it says it’s only replaced those ones too.  If the file wasn’t so large I wouldn’t have noticed it had removed other lines – in my case, it’s removed over 40k too many.

Comment: @sjw: AFAIK there is no limit of alternations. Have you tried to do the replace on an extract (about 100 lines) of your original file? Does it work? Try to add a word boundary after the alternations: `...AA)\b.*\R...`

Comment: Apologies - it works with the suggested simplified version!  I hadn't removed the .*\R.*(?:\R|$) from the second 'term'.  With it only at the end it works perfectly (and almost instantly!).  It's as though the other (mine) gets to a line (possibly a blank line or the last line of the correct result?) and then removes the rest of the file. ??